# Exercise on true or false.

Tags: calculus

If $ f $ is continuous over $ [1,3] $ and $ \int_1 ^ 3f (x) dx = 0 $, then $ f (x) = 0 $ for $ 0 \leq x \leq 1 $.

I think that is false. I'm right?

Comment: That's the right answer; how would you convince someone that you're right?

Comment: My reason is, that a definite integral gives you $ 0 $ in an interval, it does not mean that the function is $ 0 $, for the simple fact that you are evaluating, and there are functions such as the odd functions that certain integrals in them give $ 0 $ but the functions are not null. I'm trying to find the counterexample.

Comment: Excellent, you're right that a counterexample is all the proof you need!

Comment: Thanks for answering :).

Comment: To find a counter-example, draw a graph of a function with equal "area" above and below the $x$ axis on the interval [1,3]. Writing an explicit formula is not hard if you consider only linear piecewise functions.

Comment: Well, your integral condition is on $[1,3]$ and you want to prove something for $f$ on $[0,1]$... I would be $f$, I would party high on $[0,1]$ !

Comment: Take $f(x)=x-2.$ Notice that you just need to remind that "an integral is the area under the curve", so for this to be $0$ you need a positive area and then a "negative" area. Then identity shifted seems to be the simplest as candidate.

Answer (score 1):

The recipe is already hinted in the comments, and there are infinitely many choices here. One of them is to take $f(x) = 2x+c$, then $\displaystyle \int_{1}^3 f(x)dx = 0\implies c = - 4\implies f(x) = 2x-4$. Observe that $f(x)$ is not identically $0$ on $[1,3]$.